# Customized push notification Duolingo-like

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have mobile games using Firebase and while I used push-notifications before, they seem quite bland and generic. I noticed that, for example, Duolingo sends a custom push notification that stands out (icon, background color, etc) I am sending an example image below:

[image]

In contrast, you can see below how generic push notifications appear:

[image]

I dont have much knowledge in this topic, would someone kindly point out where or how I can learn more about how to do something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in Firebase since it's a customized notification that uses XML layouts. Here's a minimal version of how you do it:

First, define an XML layout (res/layout/custom_notification.xml) for your custom notification view.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:weightSum="5">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="Let’s forward your progress!"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="We're here to help you advance and achieve more."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/forward_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Koltin part:

```kotlin
    import android.app.NotificationChannel
    import android.app.NotificationManager
    import android.content.Context
    import android.os.Build
    import android.util.Log
    import android.widget.RemoteViews
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
    // Import your "R" package here
    
    object NotificationManager {
        private var isInitialized = false;
        private val channelId = "marketing_notification_channel"
    
        fun createNotification(context: Context) {
            Log.d("NotificationLib", "createNotification called")
            if (isInitialized.not()) {
                initializeMarketingNotificationChannel(context = context)
            }
    
            val notificationId = 66669 // Just a "constant" random ID
    
            val layout = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification)
    
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("Test title") // TODO take as argument
                .setContentText("Test content") // TODO take as argument
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCustomContentView(layout)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.purple))
    
            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification.build())
            Log.d("NotificationLib", "createNotification ended")
        }
    
        // Create the notification channel (for API level 26 and above)
        private fun initializeMarketingNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
            Log.d("NotificationLib", "initializeMarketingNotificationChannel called")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val name = "Marketing Channel"
                val descriptionText = "Channel for marketing notifications"
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
                    description = descriptionText
                }
                val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
                isInitialized = true;
                Log.d("NotificationLib", "initializeMarketingNotificationChannel initialized")
            } else {
                Log.d("NotificationLib", "initializeMarketingNotificationChannel NOT initialized")
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: Remember to change the `importance` and `priority`

Update: I've tested on 5 different devices and the UI varies on each device. It depends on, the brand, the model, and the OS version. So test it well and you might need to use a theme logic to handle dark/light themes.